# iOS - UISlider showing multiple values when sliding

Tags: ios, swift, uislider

I am using a `UISlider` in my app and in the `UIViewController` trying to capture its value. 
When I use the slider and change between points on it, I get the below in the terminal :

> 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1

I want to make sure I only get 0 or 1 or 2 and not multiple updates as I move. 
How can this be done? 
Here is the code I have :

```
@IBAction func sliderMoved(sender: UISlider) {
    sender.setValue(Float(lroundf(self.ladderLengthSlider.value)), animated: true)
    //print(self.ladderLengthSlider.value)
    self.ladderLength = (lroundf(self.ladderLengthSlider.value))
    self.mainObject.ladderLength = Int(ladderLength)
    print(ladderLength)
}
```

Any idea will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You need to store previous value of your slide  in global variable. and perform action only when new value is not equal to previous value.

There is no other way.

```
if sender.value == prevVal
{
return;
}

prevVal = sender.value
...
//perform other task
...
```

Answer (score 0):

set slider's

```
isContinuous = false
```

Comment: This will not restric SliderMoved to call only when its value get changed.